# Output structure for ftp dir command is different on one specific Windows IIS server

Tags: windows, ftp, iis

We are using FTP for very long time in our product. And for years now, we had no issues.

Our code expects this output for the columns:

```
ftp> dir
200 Port command successful
150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
-r--r--r-- 1 ftp ftp            177 Feb 03  2014 CEA2 file1
-r--r--r-- 1 ftp ftp            121 Feb 11  2014 CEA2 file2
```

and our code was using this:

```c
fsize = atol(ftp_entry[4])
```

Last week we had a customer using Windows NT and this crashed since the 5th column [4] is the filename in the output:

```
ftp> dir
227 Entering Passive Mode
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
10-28-20 12:54 PM 321450029 file1
```

Is that a normal output? Why Windows NT has a different output? Is that expected? I could not locate anywhere an example for that from NT documentation.

Is there any way to change the output to be identical to Linux/Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS supports two different formats of directory listing, *MS-DOS* and *UNIX*. Your code expects the *UNIX* format. But that server is configured to use the *MS-DOS* format.

To switch to the *UNIX* format, in IIS Manager, in your site panel go to *FTP > FTP Directory Browsing > Directory Listing Style > UNIX*:

[image]

*Though note that the change can break other applications that might rely on the MS-DOS format.*

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!